# installing SSL on 2 exchange servers

Tags: ssl, exchange, ssl-certificate, email-server

I have 2 exchange servers run for one email service, and I need to renew the SSL certificate. Do I need to issue 2 SSL, or one is enough?
If one is enough how can I replicate it between them?

Comment: Why exactly do you have 2 certificates today?

Comment: I did not have 2 certificates , I have 2 servers. I'm asking about how to install the certificates on both servers

Comment: How did you install the current TLS certificate being used.  If you don't have 2 TLS certificates today, then you have answered your question, if the same certificate can be used on 2 servers.

Comment: Actually another guy installed the old one,

Comment: How you install the certificate will vary based on the specifics of your infrastructure.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your assist, In the first server, I have created the request, then I got "complete" button, then I press the "complete" and point to the .cer file, I think its done. now in the second server, when I press the 3 dots button and chose import, I got this error "A special Rpc error occurs on server EX2: Cannot import certificate. A certificate with the thumbprint ............... already exists."